# Using class method to execute callback from another class instance

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, callback

```
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.health = 100;
  }
  playerDamaged(applyDamage) {
    applyDamage(this);
  }
}

class BrickWall {
  constructor() {
    this.collisionDmg = 5;
  }
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= BrickWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}

class SpikyWall {
  constructor() {
    this.collisionDmg = 25;
  }
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= SpikyWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}

const player = new Player();
const brickWall = new BrickWall();
const spikyWall = new SpikyWall();

player.playerDamaged(brickWall.playerCollision);
player.playerDamaged(spikyWall.playerCollision);

console.log(player.health);
```

In the Player class I want to be able to pass a callback to playerDamaged to apply damage to the Player's health.

My intended objective is that line when `player.playerDamaged(brickWall.playerCollision);` runs, the player's health will be reduced by 5, and when `player.playerDamaged(brickWall.playerCollision);` runs, the player's health will be reduce by another 25.

I want `console.log(player.health);` to return 70. It currently returns `NaN`.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this

```
player.health -= BrickWall.collisionDmg;
```

you're referring to `BrickWall.collisionDmg` - which would only make sense if the property is *on the class itself*, like so:

```
class BrickWall {
  static collisionDmg = 5;
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= BrickWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}
```

or

```
class BrickWall {
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= BrickWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}

BrickWall.collisionDmg = 5;
```

The class is not the instance; the instance does not inherit from the class as a prototype. (The instance inherits from the `<class>.prototype`, but not from `<class>`) So, since no property exists at `BrickWall.collisionDmg` in your code, it returns `undefined`, resulting in NaN.

Add the static properties.

```js
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.health = 100;
  }
  playerDamaged(applyDamage) {
    applyDamage(this);
  }
}

class BrickWall {
  static collisionDmg = 5;
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= BrickWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}

class SpikyWall {
  static collisionDmg = 25;
  playerCollision(player) {
    player.health -= SpikyWall.collisionDmg;
  }
}

const player = new Player();
const brickWall = new BrickWall();
const spikyWall = new SpikyWall();

player.playerDamaged(brickWall.playerCollision);
player.playerDamaged(spikyWall.playerCollision);

console.log(player.health);
```

That said, I don't think having classes for `BrickWall` and `SpikyWall` are doing that much for you here (other than making the logic uncomfortably weird to follow due to the callbacks). A class is useful when you want to tie together *data* associated with an instance with *methods* to operate on that data - but you don't have any instance data. JS isn't Java, so don't feel like you have to use a `class` just because the keyword exists. Consider a plain function instead, and then call that function, perhaps like:

```
const brickWall = player => player.health -= 25;
```

or

```
const COLLISION_DAMAGE = {
  brickWall: 5,
  spikeyWall: 25,
};
// ...
player.playerDamaged(COLLISION_DAMAGE.brickWall);
```